# Dynamic column with single select controls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Please anyone can help me to add dynamic columns in JQ Grid in which some columns having Drop down controls in it and some columns having text field to enter data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called custom formatter like `formatter:function(){}` in here you can return your specific inputs:

for Input type text:

```
formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    return '<input type="text" value="+cellvalue+" />';
}
```

*And same way you can return the select element.*

You have to put this in your each objects in `colModels`.